# How to change the frame of an instatiated Sprite2D Godot using C#?

Tags: c#, sprite, sprite-sheet, godot4

I am trying to instatntiate a Sprite2D Scene with 12 frames into my game and set the frame so that each instance uses a differnt frame. When I try to change the frame property I get a compiler error which states:

D:\Projects\Godot\Chess\Board.cs(22,12): 'Sprite2D' does not contain a definition for 'frame' and no accessible extension method 'frame' accepting a first argument of type 'Sprite2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do you modify this property?

My code is:

```
var pieceScene = GD.Load<PackedScene>("res://piece.tscn"); //This is the Sprite2D Scene
var wKing = pieceScene.Instantiate() as Sprite2D;
wKing.frame = 0;
AddChild(wKing);
```

I have also tried

```
var pieceScene = GD.Load<PackedScene>("res://piece.tscn"); //This is the Sprite 2d Scene
var wKing = pieceScene.Instantiate() as Sprite2D;
wKing.set_frame(0);
AddChild(wKing);
```

However they bring up the same error exept there is no defeniton for set_frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [Godot C# API Differences Documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_differences.html) states, most of the API for C# is in `PascalCase` compared to GDScript's API using `snake_case`. So in the case of `Sprite2D.frame` you want to use `Sprite2D.Frame` instead.